# How Deluge calculate the ration

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I use Deluge to download Ubuntu iso and seed them. In the image below you see (in French) that I downloaded 504.5 Mo and uploaded 629.4 Mo for the selected iso. The ratio is 0.914. How it is calculated? I though that the ration = uploaded/downloaded data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ratio  = uploaded bytes / downloaded bytes = 629.4  / 688.3 = 0.091442685.

I would consider the 504.5 a bug and would assume it should have been 688.3.